# Массив в функции

Tags: javascript

Интересует `new_select(..., массив)`, что в массиве именно не так? С ним не работает функция вообще. Если его убрать и подставить вместо него число например, то сработает. `new_select('sel1', 2)`

```
function new_select(id, obj) {
 array_s = obj;
 array_int = document.getElementById(id);
 for(i = 1; i <= array_s.length; i++) {
  var array_value = array_s[i][1];
  var array_text = array_s[i][2];
 }
 array_int.innerHTML = '\
 <div class="select">\
  <div id="t'+id+'" class="select_title">Выберите тип</div>\
  <div id="s'+id+'" class="selector">\
   <div class="selector_img"></div>\
  </div>\
  <div id="l'+id+'" class="select_list">\
   ad <br />asdasd <br> asd <br />\
  </div>\
</div>';

var summ_width = $('#t'+id).width() + $('#s'+id).width() + 63;
$('#l'+id).css('width', summ_width);
}

new_select('sel1', [[0, 'Выберите тип'], [1, 'Один'], [2, 'Два']]);
```

Comment: С массивом всё нормально, ищите в функции проблемы. Желательно вообще видеть листинг функции.

Comment: @stck, обновил код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Ошибка была в цикле. Необходимо было написать так:

```
i < array_s.length;
```

а не так:

```
i <= array_s.length;
```

Comment: LOL! Надо так:

         for(i = 0; i < array_s.length; i++)

а не грязь месить:

        for(i = 1; i < array_s.length; i++) {

Comment: Так вы теряете один элемент "Выберите тип"

Comment: @stck, он и должен теряться :)

Comment: @Asen - **var**??? не, не слышал

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите по знакам восклицания в приведённом коде. Неправильная индексация у Вас получалась. Массивы индексируются с 0 и соответственно последним индексом будет длина массива-1. А в остальном ничего сверхестественного. Вы пользуетесь фреймворком? Не понятно, почему вначале тогда вы ставите **document.getElementById(id);** когда можете $('#'+id). Возвращают ведь они одно и то же - элемент.

```
function new_select(id, obj) {
 array_s = obj;
 array_int = document.getElementById(id);
 for(i = /*!*/0; i <= array_s.length-1/*!*/; i++) {
  var array_value = array_s[i][1];
  var array_text = array_s[i][2];
 }
 array_int.innerHTML = '\
 <div class="select">\
  <div id="t'+id+'" class="select_title">Выберите тип</div>\
  <div id="s'+id+'" class="selector">\
   <div class="selector_img"></div>\
  </div>\
  <div id="l'+id+'" class="select_list">\
   ad <br />asdasd <br> asd <br />\
  </div>\
</div>';

var summ_width = $('#t'+id).width() + $('#s'+id).width() + 63;
$('#l'+id).css('width', summ_width);
}
```